# Using my own Rest API

Tags: asp.net, web-services, api, rest, deployment

I have been learning about Rest APIs and I just created my first one in Visual Studio. Now I would like to put it on the internet so I can call to it rather than calling localhost. For the amount of information on how to create an API there isn't much information on how to deploy it.

My API is very simple and not very useful. It is more of a learning exercise to me. So I was wondering what is the free or cheap way of getting it on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every ASP.NET project is deployed the same way. You hit publish and upload the files to a web server (be it your own computer with public IP address or hosting you pay for). If you are using a database you may need to setup that too and tweak the connection string in the config file.

Comment: No database for right now, just hard coding data. Is there a free web server that I can publish my project to?

Comment: Azure has free Web Sites (which have various limitations but will work for no database Web API). Almost every hosting provider has a trial period (usually 60 days). I am not aware of any that provide free hosting but I have not looked for any so... Just make sure the hosting supports the ASP.NET version you are using.

Comment: Thanks. Have you heard of 3scale?

Comment: No, I haven't. Looking at their site sounds like a service where you provide an API and they provide a proxy to it with additional features.